# C++ static data members initialization in initialization list

Tags: c++

Why can't static data members initialized in an constructor's initialization list while it can be done in the constructor's definition ?

Comment: How do you propose you initialize a data member in the constructor's body?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You got it wrong. They can be initialized in a single translation unit outside the class definition* and they can be **assigned to** in the constructor.

You can only initialize current non-`static` class member in the initialization list of the constructor.

<sub>*Exceptions apply</sub>

Comment: Nice answer (+1). Congrats on the 100k!

Comment: thnx for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

Static members are in class scope i.e they are class variable not instance variable.We initialize instances by constructor. As static variable are not for the instance but for the entire class so static variables are not initialized by constructor .
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this more specific

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class classWithStaticVariable
{

    static int aStaticVariable;

    int aNormalInstanceVariable;
public:
    classWithStaticVariable(int aParameter)
    {

        aNormalInstanceVariable=aParameter;

        aStaticVariable=aNormalInstanceVariable;/////It is possible to assign value to static data member in constructor but not possible to init it.

    }

    void aTestFunctionJustToPrint()
    {


        cout<<aStaticVariable<<aNormalInstanceVariable;
    }



};
int classWithStaticVariable::aStaticVariable=1;

int main()
{

    classWithStaticVariable t(2);

    t.aTestFunctionJustToPrint();


}
```

Static variable are class variable not instance variable. So these static variable must be initialized with the class definition. Again constructor is used to initialize the instance variable for an object when it is created.Thats all. Thanks